# C++ type trait with volatile

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I am trying to understand the following type trait which checks whether `T` is from the type `container` or derived from such type. My question relates to `aux_iscontainer` and its argument.

Why does it need to have the CV qualifier in front of the argument.?

Why do we even need to pass a pointer to the type and not just the type itself?

While `std::declval<T>` does just allow us to use the type of `T` without it constructing what does `std::declval<T*>` mean in this case?

```
template< typename T>
std::true_type aux_iscontainer( const volatile container<T> *);
std::false_type aux_iscontainer(... ) ;


template< typename T >
struct iscontainer : public decltype( aux_iscontainer(std::declval<T*>() ) ) 
{};

// 
template< typename T >
struct iscontainer <T&>
   : public std::false_type
 {};
```

Comment: C-ellipsis supports limited kinds of type, but pointer is fine. It also allow to support inheritance.

Comment: One question by question.

Comment: Ahh right so the whole idea of using `std::delcval<T*>` (with a pointer) is to allow for support of any type that could have been derived from T as well as T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it need to have the CV qualifier in front of the argument.?

One of the standard implicit conversions is *adding* cv qualifiers to an expression, so `const volatile T*` can bind to any of `T*`, `const T*`, `volatile T*` and `const volatile T*`.

> Why do we even need to pass a pointer to the type and not just the type itself?

Another of the standard implicit conversions is from pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base.

> While std::declval does just allow us to use the type of T without it constructing what does std::declval<T*> mean in this case?

The same, it is an expression with the type `T*` without a value of type `T*`.